# Count a consecutive streak of values in Google Sheets, if the values aren't all the same?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So, I have a Google Sheet with various readership/writing stats, and I'm using one column to log how many words I'm writing every  day. I'd like to use that column to calculate writing streaks, i.e., have a cell that records the most cells *in a row* that have any value in them (days in which I wrote any amount of words) before being interrupted by a blank cell (day in which I didn't write). I've seen formulas for counting streaks of the same consecutive value, and formulas for counting non-empty cells, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to put them together in a formula that doesn't result in an error.

Comment: It would be best if you could share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `max(len(split()))` pattern:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(join("", A2:A)), 
    max( len( split( 
      concatenate( left(isblank(A2:A)) ), 
      "T" 
    ) ) ), 
    "no streak" 
  ) 
)
```

The formula assumes that the number of words figures are in column `A2:A`.